# How to build Cocoa touch framework which use third party lib as cocoa pod?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm a iOS developer and want to build a distributed framework which use pods to integrate third party lib in framework project. Pods like SVProgressHUD and socket.io-client-swift.

I want to know what is the best way to build this kind of frameworks. Is there any tutorial given online which gives all the instructions.

I tried building a framework in above structure and it complies fine but when I'm importing this framework in other project getting errors:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Framework.framework/Framework
>   Referenced from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/73A8E170-4FE5-4CFF-B52E-C42099F32F9C/Framework.app/Framework
>   Reason: image not found

Can anyone help me. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: See this https://medium.com/captain-ios-experts/advanced-swift-ch-2-using-third-party-framework-inside-custom-swift-framework-133cefd76fcd

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the third party frameworks you are using for e.g:- socket.io-client-swift as Optional instead of Required under Link binary with Libraries in build Phases section. That's all. try it again and it will run as expected.